# module 'cv2' has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2 as cv

frameWidth = 640
frameHeight = 800

capture = cv.VideoCapture(0)
capture.set(3, frameWidth)
capture.set(4, frameHeight)
capture.set(10, 140)

while True:
    passed, frame = cv.read()
    cv.imshow('Camera Capture', frame)
    if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

capture.release()
capture.destroyAllWindows()
```

I've been trying to capture my camera using OpenCV. However it gives the error "module 'cv2' has no attribute 'read'" I looked at various codes and sources including OpenCV's own documentation. They all use the same code without errors. I tried uninstalling and installing opencv and opencv-contrib.

Comment: do you want [imread](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56)?

Comment: Did you `pip install opencv-python`?

Comment: Did you mean `capture.read()` instead of `cv.read()`?

Comment: Yeah i missed it fixed now but there's a much bigger error now.

Comment: **voting to close** because it's due to a **typo** -- please review [mre]. you could have caught this with a little more attention and debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your section of code:

```py
while True:
    passed, frame = cv.read()
    cv.imshow('Camera Capture', frame)
    if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

The issue is that you are trying to call `read()` on the module, rather you want to call read on the `cv.VideoCapture` object you created called `capture` so it should be as such.

```py
while True:
    passed, frame = capture.read()
    cv.imshow('Camera Capture', frame)
    if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the VideoCapture to read your cam, instead

```
passed, frame = capture.read()
```